# Why is my if statement not working: Unexpected ! after ||

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

My text editor and php says unexpected `!` after the `||` someone know this bug ? This is very weird

```
foreach($data as $pile->data) 
    if(!is_float($data) || ! is_int($data)) 
        die('Pile::sort() invalid $pile data');
```

I use VS code as text editor and 
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2020 18:39:59) ( NTS )

Comment: Can you post the rest of the condition? Curly brackets and all.

Comment: The statement you're showing us is [valid](https://3v4l.org/EeW3u) php.

Comment: Which text editor, I know some of them can be a bit slow to update, sometimes removing the line and pasting it back in sorts out the notification.

Comment: Do not over think about the editors. If your code works then you are good to go

Comment: But OP says PHP reports the error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, old versions are unable to distinguish multiple scenarios and spaces if added intentionally. 
first of all, use this modified code.

```
foreach($data as $pile->data) 
if((!is_float($data)) || (!is_int($data))) 
    die('Pile::sort() invalid $pile data');
```

Otherwise, please try to update to the latest version or do perform multiple checks. If the issue is still there, please do contact the official tool sport or read the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this error, I had to update my editor and download the last version of Wamp. 
Not sure why but it worked for me. Maybe you should try it

Answer (score 0):

I updated my php and now this is working.